# Question how to use -ts or -tr flags in gdalwarp for resampling

Tags: gdal

I run a complex cpp application, where gdal (3.5.3) is a part to get elevation data from eudem v 1.1. The eudem files are quite large and I want to reduce their file size, since I don't need an accuracy of 25m. This is one file I use and want to downsize.

````
    gdalinfo E20N20.TIF
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: E20N20.TIF
Size is 40000, 40000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["ETRS89_ETRS_LAEA",
    GEOGCS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010042,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",52],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",10],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",4321000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",3210000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (2000000.000000000000000,3000000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (25.000000000000000,-25.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Elevation
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 2000000.000, 3000000.000) ( 20d45'24.21"W, 45d41'42.74"N)
Lower Left  ( 2000000.000, 2000000.000) ( 16d36'13.25"W, 37d23'21.20"N)
Upper Right ( 3000000.000, 3000000.000) (  8d 7'39.52"W, 48d38'23.47"N)
Lower Right ( 3000000.000, 2000000.000) (  5d28'46.07"W, 39d52'33.70"N)
Center      ( 2500000.000, 2500000.000) ( 12d41'50.60"W, 43d 6' 4.82"N)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-3.4028234663852886e+38
  Metadata:
    BandName=Band_1
    RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC

```

I tried the following cmd, but w/out success. Its probably about wrong ts or tr values; 

```
gdalwarp -r average -tr 1024 1024 -wm 4096 -multi -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co TILED=YES \
-co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS E20N20.TIF dz_E20N20.TIF
Creating output file that is 977P x 977L.
Processing E20N20.TIF [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. -3.40282e+38) for image E20N20.TIF.
Copying nodata values from source E20N20.TIF to destination dz_E20N20.TIF.
ERROR 1: Integer overflow : nSrcXSize=19989, nSrcYSize=19989
ERROR 1: Integer overflow : nSrcXSize=20012, nSrcYSize=19989

```
I'm lost, here.
````

Comment: I cannot replicate this issue on my machine, with the same eudem file. Why pick 1024 meter as the output resolution, instead of for example 1000m?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your GDAL coming from, this is a 32-bit error because your data exceeds 4GB?

Also, unless you are reprojecting, I strongly advise you to use `gdal_translate` instead which has much better performance when resampling:

```
gdal_translate -r average -tr 1024 1024 -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co TILED=YES \
  -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS E20N20.TIF dz_E20N20.TIF
```

You can probably use the official Docker images if you need another GDAL build.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time. I found the problem in `-wm 4096`. I use the Linux Subsystem for windows to make the resampling. I used 1024 a power of 2, because I didn't really understand, how -ts or -ts worked. I finally use:

```
gdalwarp -r average -ts 8000 8000 -multi -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co TILED=YES \
  -co NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS E20N20.TIF dz_E20N20.TIF
```

This reduces my file size about 75% and the pixel dim moves from 25x25m to 125x125m.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a complete resolution of this issue (with example) [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349818/resample-raster-from-one-resolution-to-another-with-gdal-python-api/477663#477663). The `-tr` flag you will need to pass the pixel size, then `-ts` is about the desired image dimension.

In this link, I have described a way to downsample a worldview-3 image to a lower resolution (worldview-2), by choosing a worldview-2 reference image and taking its metadata pixel size by `gdalinfo`:

```
X_RES = gdalinfo -mm $PATH_TO_REFERENCE_IMAGE_WITH_LOWER_RESOLUTION | grep "Pixel Size" | grep "\([0-9]\.[0-9]\+\)\,\([-w][0-9]\.[0-9]\+\)"
```

then, run it to every worldview-3 image. Here, the complete solution:

```
PATH_TO_HIGHER_RESOLUTION_IMAGES=$1
PATH_TO_REFERENCE_IMAGE_WITH_LOWER_RESOLUTION=$2
PATH_TO_OUTPUT=$3

RESAMPLE_METHOD="cubic"
X_RES="0.5"

# TODO: get pixel size
#X_RES = gdalinfo -mm $PATH_TO_REFERENCE_IMAGE_WITH_LOWER_RESOLUTION | grep "Pixel Size" | grep "\([0-9]\.[0-9]\+\)\,\([-w][0-9]\.[0-9]\+\)"
#echo $X_RES

if [ -z "$X_RES" ]; then
    echo "\$X_RES resolution is empty"
fi

for image in $PATH_TO_HIGHER_RESOLUTION_IMAGES*.TIF; do
    filename=$(basename $image)

    if [[ ! -e $PATH_TO_OUTPUT ]]; then
        mkdir $PATH_TO_OUTPUT
    elif [[ ! -d $PATH_TO_OUTPUT ]]; then
        echo "$PATH_TO_OUTPUT already exists but is not a directory" 1>&2
    fi

    result_image=$PATH_TO_OUTPUT$filename

    gdalwarp -of GTiff -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co TILED=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -tr $X_RES $X_RES -r $RESAMPLE_METHOD $image $result_image
done
```

and usage:

```
./resample.sh ../folder-with-higher-resolution/ ../folder-with-lower-resolution/REFERENCE_IMAGE.TIF ../output-resampled-images/
```